# Child not re-rendering in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm writing an app for playing different audio files (play them in loops). In the app I want multiple files to be able to play simultaneously , but they need to start at the same point. This means additional audio tracks I have activated would only start playing upon completion of an already playing audio file's loop.

My components are currently two -

1. App.js (presents different audio files), **parent**.
2. Play.js (present the option to play and stop each audio file), **child** .
   I'm trying to pass an update (via hooks) to the parent once an audio file has started to play, but each time I do such an update I lose the functionality the children i.e. I can start playing a file but can't stop it.

This is the code of my child:

```
import React from 'react';


export function Play(props) {

 
 let currentlyPlaying = false;
 
 let audio = new Audio(props.audioClip.sound);
 const start = () => {
   console.log(currentlyPlaying);
   if (!currentlyPlaying) {
     props.onStart(); //problematic line, stops re-rendering of child
     audio.play()
     currentlyPlaying = true;
     audio.loop = true;
   }
 }

 const stop = () => {
   currentlyPlaying = false;
   audio.pause()
   audio.currentTime = 0;
 }


 return (
   <div>

     <p>Hear the sound of {props.audioClip.label}!: </p>
     <button onClick={start}  >Playyyy day</button>
     <button onClick={stop}>Stop me!</button>
   </div >
 );
}

export default Play
```

This is the code of my parent:

```
function App () {
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
    // const [playingAnySong, setPlaying] = useState(false);
    const [audioClips, setAudioClips] = useState([
      { sound: Bass, label: 'Funky Bass', playing: false },
      { sound: futureFunk, label: 'Future Funk', playing: false },
      { sound: stutterBeats, label: 'Stuttering Beats', playing: false },
      { sound: electricGuitar, label: 'Electric country guitar', playing: false },
      { sound: StompySlosh, label: 'Stompin rythm', playing: false },
      { sound: groove, label: 'Groovyyy', playing: false },
      { sound: MazePolitics, label: 'The Maze', playing: false },
      { sound: pas3, label: 'Sachi drums', playing: false },
      { sound: organSynth, label: 'Psychedelic Organ', playing: false },
    ])


    return (
      <div className="container">
        {audioClips.map((audio, i) => {
          return <Play key={i} onStart={value => setCounter(counter + 1)} audioClip = {audio} />
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }




export default App;
```

I have a feeling that I'm doing something wrong regarding the updating the state for the parent.
Could you identify why my app stops functioning every time I update the parent?

Comment: why do you have this line of code `onStart={value => setCounter(counter + 1)}`

Comment: It's a mistake. I wanted to pass to the children the ability to update the parent's state for counting the number of active audio files (the ability to update 'counter').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your play component use state for the currentlyPlaying and the audio.

```
import React, {FC, useState} from 'react';


export const Play: FC <any> = ({audioClip, onStart}) => {

 const [currentlyPlaying, setCurrentlyPlaying] = useState(false)
 const [audio] = useState(new Audio(audioClip.sound)) // to keep track of the audio of the component

 const start = () => {
   console.log(currentlyPlaying);
   if (!currentlyPlaying) {
     onStart(); //problematic line, stops re-rendering of child
     audio.play()
     audio.loop = true;
     setCurrentlyPlaying(true)
   }
 }

 const stop = () => {
   setCurrentlyPlaying(false);
   audio.pause();
   audio.currentTime = 0;
 }

 return (
   <div>
     <p>Hear the sound of {audioClip.label}!: </p>
     <button onClick={start}  >Playyyy day</button>
     <button onClick={stop}>Stop me!</button>
   </div >
 );
}

export default Play
```

In your App component, declare a function for the onStart props because your currently code make the play component rerender each time there is an update in the App component.

```
function App () {
const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
// const [playingAnySong, setPlaying] = useState(false);
const [audioClips, setAudioClips] = useState([
  { sound: Bass, label: 'Funky Bass', playing: false },
  { sound: futureFunk, label: 'Future Funk', playing: false },
  { sound: stutterBeats, label: 'Stuttering Beats', playing: false },
  { sound: electricGuitar, label: 'Electric country guitar', playing: false },
  { sound: StompySlosh, label: 'Stompin rythm', playing: false },
  { sound: groove, label: 'Groovyyy', playing: false },
  { sound: MazePolitics, label: 'The Maze', playing: false },
  { sound: pas3, label: 'Sachi drums', playing: false },
  { sound: organSynth, label: 'Psychedelic Organ', playing: false },
])
const handleStart = value => setCounter(counter + 1)


return (
  <div className="container">
    {audioClips.map((audio, i) => {
      return <Play key={i} onStart={handleStart} audioClip = {audio} />
    })}
  </div>
);

}

export default App;
```

Comment: could you show me what you mean by "declare a function for the onStart props because your currently code make the play component rerender each time there is an update in the App component."? 
I added a state for currently playing:

export function Play(props) {
 const [currentlyPlaying, setCurrentlyPlaying] = useState(false);

Comment: Firstly, Thanks man! I added the function you advised me to add, but unfortunately I still have the same problem - every update I make to a state (both parent and child states) in the child component block my code and stop its functionality (I can't stop a track once it has started).

Comment: If you comment the audio.loop, you still have the problem ?

Comment: can you show what kind of object the sound is ?

Comment: erased the audio loop, I recursively call start instead(). Still have the problem.

Comment: what do you mean by "kind of object"? Its a static mp3 file that has been transformed to an Audio file in react.

Comment: Updated the answer, it was because you didn't use state with the audio, the state of the component is lost each time it rerenders and the audio you stopped was not the audio you played. It works now :)